# How to make (almost) the same Bitbucket repository and keep them both synced?

Tags: git, synchronization, bitbucket

We have our repository on Bitbucket.

I need to make another one which have same content minus one file, but without history of original one.
These repositories need to be synced from now on, except that one important file which needs to be just on our original repository.

What is the smart way for do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a little bit awkward regarding the important file... but here is one strategy to create your new repo without this file. You will be able to pull from the original repo, but if you push back to it (or pull the other way) it will remove the file from the original repo :(  ... This is because git works on commits and not individual files.

First make a fresh repo with the files from the particular branch/commit:

```
# clone the repo into a new repo (just making it locally for now)
git clone <url> newrepo
# Move into the repo
cd newrepo
# Checkout the commit you want (e.g. a branch name called "mybranch")
checkout mybranch
# Delete the .git folder - this changes it from a cloned repo to just a bunch of files
rm -rf .git
# Now make this folder into a new repo
git init
# Now add this "pile of files" into the repo
git add .
# First commit
git commit -m "First commit created from repo <url>"
```

Now delete the file you want to get rid of (you could do this before the first commit if you did not want this in the history):

```
git rm somefile
git commit -m "removed unwanted file"
```

Now add a remote (called sync or whatever you want to call it) to the origin url

```
git remote add sync <url>
```

So now you can do pulls from the original repo. However you have to be careful not to push back your "important file". The problem here is that anything you do in one repo will be sync'd to the other repo (so if you push your changes back to the remote "sync" (the original repo) then it will push the "deleted" file...

Again - if you add the file to the .gitignore, this will be picked up in both repos once you sync... So maybe you need to just stick this one important file into a separate repo entirely and the user needs to clone that if they need it...

Note: in your new repo use `git pull sync mybranch` to merge in changes from the original repo/mybranch.

Note: When you do this pull (as above) you will see your local history tree merged with the history tree of the remote sync repo. So after the first pull you will still see only 2 commits in your branch, but you will also see (using say `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` the tree from the remote "sync".